Laplace vs Fourier transform: Which you recommend for steady-state circuit analysis?
(1) obtain the transient target voltage (or current) using the Laplace transform, and then calculate the limit t -> inf.
(2) use Fourier transform
Thank you.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

For linear systems analysis there is no reason to use Fourier transform over Laplace transform.
Fourier transformation can only be used to analyze systems that are asymptotically stable. Laplace transform can analyze asymptotically and marginally stable systems, as well as unstable systems.
Moreover, Fourier transformation can only be applied to signals that are non-increasing. The Fourier transform of a ramp function \$tu(t) \$ doesn't exist, for example. The Laplace transform exists for increasing, decreasing and periodic signals.

If the circuit has a DC steady state it can be found by treating inductors as conductors and capacitors as insulators.
If it does not, then Laplace and Fourier transforms will give the same result with different representations.
